# Angular module functions: using var?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm pretty new to Angular, but a recent problem I debugged in my application went as follows:

Say I'm attaching a new directive to an existing module defined in another .js file. When I use the following syntax:

```
angular
.module('myApp')
.directive('ratingStars', ratingStars)
;

var ratingStars = function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {thisRating : '=rating'},
    templateUrl: '/my.template.html'
  };
};
```

I would get an error, along the lines of "Argument 'fn' is not a function, got undefined".

However, I could fix the code using the following (note the use of function directly rather than assigning to a var).

```
angular
.module('myApp')
.directive('ratingStars', ratingStars)
;

function ratingStars(){
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {thisRating : '=rating'},
    templateUrl: '/my.template.html'
  };
}
```

> What is the logical difference between taking my function and assigning to a var, rather than defining the function outright? 
>   Is some sort of variable hoisting going on? Is my var only local to that one file?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its related to [top hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var).

> What is the logical difference between taking my function and assigning to a var, rather than defining the function outright?

In the first script,

Your script is interpreted as follows.

```
var ratingStars;

angular
    .module('myApp')
    .directive('ratingStars', ratingStars);

ratingStars = function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: { thisRating: '=rating' },
        templateUrl: '/my.template.html'
    };
};
```

So,you can see,*`var ratingStars` is `declared first and assigned it to the directive definition`.Its because variable in JavaScript declared using `var` is top hoisted at function scope  which `block scope` or global scope.
`But actual definition will occur after that`.*

**In the second script**,

Your `function definition`,will be defined at the top of global code.
So,it getting interpreted correctly.

So, first one used [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) where the `variable getting top hoisted`

but `not actual function definition` and second one uses [function defination](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function)

where `function defination itself getting top hoisted`

Comment: Why it is  down-voted.?Please add comment